# Genetic engineering for experimenting at home?

Tags: human-biology, genetics

I am just wondering whether it is possible to carry out small scale genetic engineering at home, without any sophiscated tools.
Ive searched google and found this http://explorebiotech.com/the-7-important-molecular-tools-used-in-genetic-engineering/
So i am wondering whether these tools are easily acquirable and how feasible it is to be done at home maybe as a hobby.
Also my budger is probably about 200 USD so my hopes arent that high.

Comment: FYI the thermocycler in your link is almost 4,000 USD. It's a Sensoquest Labcycler model. Lab consumables like plasticware can also be quite expensive (around $2 per 6/24/96-well plate, cases often come with 50-100).

Answer (score 3):

Doing genetic engineering experiments at home is generally referred to as either "biohacking" or "[DIY Bio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-it-yourself_biology)". There's a number of forums out there filled with hobbyists who are doing that sort of work in their homes and garages, and discuss how to do such things in a hobbyist environment. With those terms (and the info in the Wikipedia article), you can probably find those forums on the internet. (Suggestion: look for ones where the regulars emphasize safety and appropriate conduct - not only is it better for you, it's a sign that the regulars know what they're talking about.)

However, 200 USD might be a little small to set up a decent (and safe) "biohacking" space in your own home. Possibly a better bet is to see if you can find a local "[makerspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hackerspace)" which has a biology component. Makerspaces are places where, for a small fee, fellow enthusiasts pool together to purchase equipment (and space) to do various projects. Most makerspaces are geared toward the computational/mechanical (e.g. building robots), but there are some out there which have biotech equipment. Your mileage may vary, though, and you're likely to have more success in finding a decent makerspace in a large city than in a small town.

A final caveat is to make sure you research your local laws to figure out what is legal in the jurisdiction you're living. Especially with laws targeting illegal drug production, there are locations where possession of basic scientific equipment by normal homeowners is criminalized. There's also regulations about waste disposal and material storage that you'll need to follow. Also, in most jurisdictions accidents/damage from home labs are penalized much more harshly than, e.g., cooking accidents. Know what's legal/illegal in your jurisdiction (and by your homeowner's insurance) before attempting to set up a home lab.

Comment: There are also dedicated 'Biohckspaces' (well, there is at least one in [London](https://biohackspace.org))

Comment: How much would you reckon I will have to spend for decent equipments etc if there isnt any markerspaces around me.

Comment: @user35897 That depends heavily on what you want to do and how "DIY" you're willing to get. For example, you don't need a thermocycler to do PCR. All you need is three heat baths at the appropriate temperature and a lot of patience. And they don't have to be "official" heat baths - you can rig something up with heating elements and thermostats. -- That's why I suggested the dedicated forums. They have the knowledge and experience to walk you through "on the cheap" options that fit your DIY comfort levels. (Which is not something that really fits StackExchange's Q&A format.)